# How to disable or remove Intel SMM?

Tags: security, bios, acer-aspire, firmware, flashing

I have successfully removed Intel ME from the firmware by reflashing the BIOS using corna's tool:

- https://github.com/corna/me_cleaner

However I am still concerned about SMM. Intel ME and AMT vulnerabilities are horrible and classified as ring -3, however the SMM module also has plenty of vulnerabilities and possible rootkits and are classified as ring -2 vulnerability.

I would like to remove or disable completely the SMM module as well. It is an Acer-Aspire laptop with an Insyde BIOS on it.

I don't know to what degree the removal of the ME system affected the SMM module, do I need to remove the SMM as well? Is it possible at all? If so please tell me whether there are any other similar tools like corna's tool for ME that can remove the SMM as well.

Comment: For SMM to be compromised, the attacking code must acquire kernel permissions on your computer. So why would it bother already with SMM, especially since whatever it did would be wiped out on reboot? My advice is that SMM is not a danger. Trying to eradicate it **is** a danger.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to buy hardware you trust. The primary example is [CoreBoot](https://www.coreboot.org/). There are system integrators who sell CoreBoot based computers.

If you buy from System76 or Purism you are supporting people who are building free and open firmware so you don't have to go down the path you are on.

**ADDITIONAL READING:**

- https://puri.sm/projects/coreboot/
- https://opensource.com/article/19/11/coreboot-system76-laptops

Answer (score 0):

[System Management Mode (SMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode):

> SMM is entered via the SMI (system management interrupt), which is invoked by:
>
> - Motherboard hardware or chipset signaling via a designated pin SMI# of the processor chip. This signal can be an independent event.
> - Software SMI triggered by the system software via an I/O access to a location considered special by the motherboard logic (port 0B2h is
>   common).
> - An I/O write to a location which the firmware has requested that the processor chip act on.

This means that triggering SMM is a motherboard function, so depending on the
motherboard firmware to be either enabled or not.
The motherboard firmware itself is digitally protected from modification.
SMM is specifically not an
[Intel Management Engine (ME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine)
function.

The SMM code that is triggered is part of the BIOS, which itself cannot
be modified without possessing the manufacturer's digital key.
SMM can however be subverted by changing the SMI interrupt address
to point to code introduced by the attacker.

All these actions require the attacker to operate inside kernel mode
in order to subvert the SMI address and SMM code, and exploits do exist
for that, as you have noted above.
However, beside the intellectual satisfaction of such an exploit, its utility
is doubtful:

- Any SMM exploit will not survive a reboot
- Subverting SMM requires the attacker to operate in kernel space,
  therefore to already be in control of the computer
- The SMI interrupt is not called by Windows, so subverting it is not useful.

My belief is that disabling or disactivating SMM is not possible,
but its presence in your computer (if it's present) is not a vulnerability
that an attacker would need (or bother) to attack.

Because SMM is opaque to the operating system, it is not possible to test
in Windows its presence or its correct functionality.
Microsoft requires motherboard vendors to deliver a robust and secure
platform, where SMM code was carefully analyzed and protected.
To that effect, the vendor must confirm to Windows via the ACPI
that certain security best practices have been implemented in SMM.

For details see the article
[Understanding the Windows SMM Security Mitigation Table (WSMT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-uefi-wsmt).

Comment: Your answer is written from the point of view of a malicious "attacker", whereas the question is rightly from the point of view of the owner of the machine as a "defender", trying to keep unknown and unvetted code from the manufacturer from persisting and running in a context that interrupts their kernel.

Comment: So many people misunderstand the problem of SMM as attack surface that an outside attacker can compromise to potentially gain persistence. This is a possibility but a remote one. The far greater problem is that, by asynchronously interrupting the real OS you actually trust, it can introduce bugs and instability to the OS, potentially leading to crashes or even causing new exploitable faults in the OS. For a good example, see https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204807#c37 where unsynchronized access to indexing registers can cause wrong hardware to be accessed.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: Agreed, SMM is a lousy attack vector, which is what my answer is trying to convey. Many people find alarming the notion of built-in firmware software that is not user-controllable, but there are many such inside the computer, basically built-into almost every non-trivial hardware component. Disabling any of these firmwares will cripple the computer partially or fully.

Comment: The question is how to prevent code from running in SMM not whether it's an attack vector. You can reasonably assume "you" (the defender) have kernel mode code execution because it's your system you're trying to get SMM code out of. What plausible methods are there for gaining control of the contents of SMRAM or SMI interrupt address to replace it with code that just does `RSM`?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: There are methods for that and lengthy articles describing such exploits. If interested, you can have a look for example at [Code Check(mate) in SMM](https://www.synacktiv.com/en/publications/code-checkmate-in-smm.html#) and also [SMMMmmmm - when root is not enough](https://barbieauglend.re/2019-08-15-system-managing-god/).

Comment: All the ones I've seen, including those, seem to be from the perspective of trying to exploit bugs in the code running in SMM (especially SWSMI handlers), which isn't very conducive to general SMM-disabling solutions, but of course could work for a specific known board. Are there general techniques that just rely on having unlimited privileges outside of SMM?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: I don't believe that this is possible, but I've seen exploits in other areas that did the seemingly impossible.

Comment: This suggests there might be general approaches that work on large classes of machines: https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/uploads/IMG/pdf/Cansec_final.pdf. I'm actually interested in older (pre-Spectre) hardware which is likely not to have mitigated such things yet.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: I can't help you there, I'm not that deeply into the subject.